# Checking Android device camera video supports at least 30fps

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I need to have a function that tells whether I the phone's camera video supports at least 30fps.
I'm using both camera1 and camera2 api, depending on the phone's camera2 support (or lack thereof)

I though about using this :

```
val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
val cameras = manager.cameraIdList
for (camera in cameras) {
     val cc = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camera)
     val fpsRange = cc.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES)!!
-->  Log.d("TAG", "fps : ${fpsRange.find { it.lower == 30 && it.upper == 30 }}") // is this correct?
}
```

but I'm not sure whether it's the right solution, I don't understand the ranges that I get and whether I chose the right CameraCharacteristics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That expression will evaluate to true for a fixed 30fps frame rate (minimum frame rate=maximum frame rate=30).  That will be generally supported on all Android devices, since it's required for standard video recording.

Comment: thank you for your response. Just to clarify - I need to know the Encoder's capabilities of compressing frames to video because our algorithm (which receives this eventually) results depend on it. 
So to be precise - we need at least 24 for it to work properly.
Can I simply check  in the last line : `it.lower >= 24` in order to address this compatibility check?  Thank you again sir.

Comment: You're querying camera output capabilities here, not encoder encoding capabilities. They're not guaranteed to match, though basically any device will encode at 30fps for typical resolutions (720p, 1080p).   If you actually care about the encoder, you should query it instead of the camera; if you care about end-to-end, take a look at CamcorderProfiles, which define end-to-end settings for common recording use cases.